# Valid JSON still getting parse error

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Gears Live Wallpaper",
        "url": "market://details?id=com.appbasic.gearslivewallpaper",
        "image": "http://appbasic.com/promimg/gearslivewallpaper.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Phone hanging too much ?",
        "url": "market://details?id=com.indiaapps.speedmaster",
        "image": "http://appbasic.com/promimg/speedmaster1.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rainbow Photo Frames",
        "url": "market://details?id=com.appbasic.rainbowphotoframes",
        "image": "http://appbasic.com/promimg/rainbowphotoframes.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Military Photo Suit",
        "url": "market://details?id=com.appbasic.militaryphotosuit",
        "image": "http://appbasic.com/promimg/militaryphotosuit.png"
    }
]
```

I am using google gson library. The code I have is:

```
try {
    URL twitter = new URL(
            "http://www.javaexperience.com/android/apps.json");
    URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            tc.getInputStream()));

    Gson gson=new Gson();

    TypeToken<List<ExitPropsBean>> token = new TypeToken<List<ExitPropsBean>>() {};
    MenuActivity.apps = gson.fromJson(in, token.getType());

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The ExitPropsBean.java is:

```
public final class ExitPropsBean {

   private Bitmap image;
   private String name;
   private String url;


   public final String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public final String getUrl() {
      return this.url;
   }

   public final Bitmap getImage() {
      return this.image;
   }

   public final void setName(String var1) {
      this.name = var1;
   }

   public final void setUrl(String var1) {
      this.url = var1;
   }

   public final void setImage(Bitmap var1) {
      this.image = var1;
   }
}
```

The exception that I get is (Expected BRGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 104):

http://prntscr.com/76mzyg

Could some one help please.

Comment: Please show us the code to the `ExitPropsBean` class. There is probably a type misalignment there.

Comment: My bad, missed it earlier. added it now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `ExitPropsBean`, you have this property:

```
private Bitmap image;
```

Gson is trying to put a `java.lang.String` into it. Either change the type from `Bitmap` to `String`, or provide a [custom deserializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) for this type.